# Javascript: Some Variables Defined, Some Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, random, undefined

I am writing a basic casino javascript game that will randomly pick 3 numbers 1-10. If each number is 7, it will display an alert box saying 'You Win!'. In the function below:

```
function StartSpin(){
        var one;
        var two;
        var three;
        var cone;
        var ctwo;
        var cthree;
        var one = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var two = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var three = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        if(one == 1){var cone = "Ace";}
        if(two == 1){var ctwo = "Ace";}
        if(three == 1){var cthree = "Ace";}
        document.getElementsByClassName("Spinner")[0].innerHTML= cone
        document.getElementsByClassName("Spinner")[1].innerHTML= ctwo
        document.getElementsByClassName("Spinner")[2].innerHTML= cthree
    }
```

On the actual page before clicking the button to start randomizing it says:
--|--|--. When clicking it, it sets the --'s to the randomized number. Every number/-- set says undefined except sometimes one will say 'Ace' meaning it was 1. So it might say: undefined|Ace|undefined, or undefined|undefined|undefined, etc.
Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="GameOne">
    <h1>~ Game One ~</h1>
    <h2>Try to get three 7's!</h2>
    <span class="so Spinner">--</span> | 
    <span class="st Spinner">--</span> | 
    <span class="sth Spinner">--</span>
    <br/>
    <button id="SpinButton" onclick="StartSpin()">Spin!</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT: I re-defined variables to see if that would help the undefined problem(In the javascript code fyi)**

Comment: Why are you redefining variables several times?

Comment: `cone`, `ctwo` and `cthree` are only defined if their respective values are 1.

Comment: Removed everything i typed as Hobo Sapiens has posts pretty much the same thing. **if** `one` / `two` doesn't ==1 `cone` ,  `ctwo` and `cthree` are undefined.

Comment: that s his logic, i guess he knows why he did that. If he does not.... Well maybe should do something else, right ?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you are only giving your variables values other than `undefined` if you randomly get the number `1`. Otherwise they stay `undefined` - which is the default value of variables in JavaScript.

Here's some seriously cleaned up logic:

http://jsbin.com/milibusaxe/1/edit?html,js,output

```
function roll() {
  var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  return (n === 1 ? 'Ace!' : n);
}

function StartSpin(){
  var slots = document.getElementsByClassName("Spinner");

  for (var i = 0, e = slots.length; i < e; i++) {
    slots[i].innerHTML = roll();
  }
}

document.getElementById('SpinButton').addEventListener('click', StartSpin);
```

As a side note, three sevens or three ones? Might want to make up your mind on that one.

Answer (score 1):

They are being set to undefined because you are only setting the variables (cone, ctwo, cthree) when a 1 is randomly selected. I assume if an ace isn't drawn you want the number to be displayed?

```
function StartSpin() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

       if (num == 1) {
           num = 'Ace';
       }

       document.getElementsByClassName("Spinner")[i].innerHTML = num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I want the number to be displayed even if its not an ace. I tried this code and it doesn't say undefined, but it does in the Chrome Log. It wont display the actual number, just ace.

Answer (score 1):

You define the `cone`, `ctwo` and `ctree`only if `one`, `two` or `three` (respectively) equals to 1. Otherwise, variables are not initiated and that's why they are undefined.

See [undefined](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp)

You can try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/0jaxL1hb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having some trouble with how variables work. `cone`, `ctwo`, & `cthree` are undefined in most cases unless you get a `1`. Also you only need to declare `var` in front of a variable when you create it. Later references just use the variable name:

```
var i = 1;
var j = i + 5;
console.log("i is", i, "and j is", j); // will print `i is 1 and j is 5`
```

A declared variable without a set value will be `undefined`

```
var k;
console.log(k); // will print `undefined`
```

In you code you are trying to transform `1` into the string "Ace", but you end up throwing out the values in `one`, `two`, and `three` in ALL other cases. This should work instead:

```js
function StartSpin() {
  // Function to make a number between 1 and 10, if 1 return "Ace" instead
  function randomNumberOrAce() {
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    // Check here if it's a `1`, and return "Ace instead", otherwise return the previously stored value
    if (number === 1) {
      return "Ace";
    } else {
      return number;
    }
  }

  // Fill in the first three elements of ".Spinner" with three random numbers
  document.getElementsByClassName("Spinner")[0].innerHTML = randomNumberOrAce();
  document.getElementsByClassName("Spinner")[1].innerHTML = randomNumberOrAce();
  document.getElementsByClassName("Spinner")[2].innerHTML = randomNumberOrAce();
}
```

```html
<div id="GameOne">
  <h1>~ Game One ~</h1>
  <h2>Try to get three 7's!</h2>
  <span class="so Spinner">--</span> |
  <span class="st Spinner">--</span> |
  <span class="sth Spinner">--</span>
  <br/>
  <button id="SpinButton" onclick="StartSpin()">Spin!</button>
</div>
```